# Where to get Duty Free Liqour in UAE?

Tags: alcohol, duty-free, uae

Is there any place from where we can get liquor products at duty free prices in United Arab Emirates?

Comment: could you be more specific? Where in the UAE are you going? Dubai?

Comment: *In* the UAE, or on departure from the UAE? (Makes a big difference!)

Comment: Dubai airport duty free is one of the best in the world. Does that work for you?

Comment: Are you going to travel across UAE or just to specific location? If you are going to Dubai or Abudhabi then you can buy liquor at lenience wine shop at Airports. If you are traveling across UAE, you better get it ordered from an online store.

Comment: Actually I am on a diplomatic mission to UAE and will be travelling across UAE. It would be nice if anyone can suggest an online store for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get liquor from a diplomatic store then you can get online from flemingo international's online store http://www.flemingodiplomatic.com/Flemingo/AlcoholicBeverages.aspx